# Align Nested 2 column list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, multicol

could someone tell me how to edit this list so that the bullet point aligns with the First letter of the "Item" and the non itemized "Align with Bullet" Text aligns with the Bullets as well?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount,enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{%
    \par\vbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
 \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex,leftmargin=*]
\item Item 1
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 2
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 3
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
    \item Fill Text
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
\end{itemize}
\item Item 4
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
\NoIndent{Aligned with Bullet} 
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 5
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done through the `wide=0pt` option. Anyway, your text `\NoIndent{...}` had no chance to align with the bullet, because of the way it is defined: `\linewidth` is the width of the column, not of the lines in the list.

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount,enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{%
    \par\vbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep}
 \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex, leftmargin=*]
\item Item 1
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 2
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 3
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Fill Text
    \item Fill Text
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
\end{itemize}
\item Item 4
 \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]
    \item Fill Text

    Aligned with Bullet. Lalala… Lalala… Lalala… Lalala…
\NoIndent{Not Aligned with Bullet. Sigh!}
    \item Fill Text
\end{itemize}
\item Item 5
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! I just wondered whether you would prefer to have the enumeration horizontally displayed (I mean  1, then     2 on the same line, n3 \the 4 on the following line, &c.)?